# How to retrive data from dynamic text box using Blazor

Tags: textbox, submit, form-submit, blazor, dynamic-forms

MyCustomControl.razor

```
<input type="text" id="@id" />
@code {
     [Parameter]
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

Test.Razor

```
@page "/test"

<button @onclick="@addCompoment">add text box</button>
<div class="simple-list-list">
    @if (componentListTest == null)
    {
        <p>You have no items in your list</p>
    }
    else
    {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var item in componentListTest)
            {
                @item<br/>
            }
        </ul>
    }
</div>

@functions {

    private List<RenderFragment> componentListTest { get; set; }
    private int currentCount { get; set; }
    private string TxtExample { get; set; }
    protected  void OnInit()
    {
        currentCount = 0;
        componentListTest = new List<RenderFragment>();
    }


    protected void addCompoment()
    {
        if(componentListTest==null)
        {
        componentListTest = new List<RenderFragment>();
        }
        componentListTest.Add(CreateDynamicComponent(currentCount));
        currentCount++;
    }


    RenderFragment CreateDynamicComponent(int counter) => builder =>
    {

        try
        {
            var seq = 0;
            builder.OpenComponent(seq, typeof(MyCustomControl));
            builder.AddAttribute(++seq, "id", "listed-" + counter);
            builder.CloseComponent();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }


    };
}
```

After Adding the textbox dynamically,how to retrieve all input data from the textbox (after clicking on the submit button.)
How to interact with dynamic component and fetch Value.
MyCustomControl is component, Append in Test Razor Page.
for these component create an attribute like bind-value to get input field data given by user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions to this type of issue, depending on the general design of your app, constraints, and such like. The following solution is simple. Generally speaking, it involves passing the value of the added text box to a parent component to be saved in a list object. The parent component has a button that displays the list of text when clicked.

The following is the definition of the child component:

### MyCustomControl.razor

```
    <input type="text" @bind="@Value" id="@ID" />

    @code {
        private string _value;

        public string Value
        {
            get { return _value; }

            set
            {
                if (_value != value)
                {
                    _value = value;
                    if (SetValue.HasDelegate)
                    {
                        SetValue.InvokeAsync(value);
                    }
                 }
             }
         }

        [Parameter]
        public string ID { get; set; }
        [Parameter]
        public EventCallback<string> SetValue { get; set; }
    }
```

### Usage in a parent component

```
    <button @onclick="@addCompoment">add text box</button>

    <div class="simple-list-list">
        @if (componentListTest == null)
        {
            <p>You have no items in your list</p>
        }
        else
        {
            <ul>
                @foreach (var item in componentListTest)
                {
                    @item
                    <br />
                }
            </ul>
        }
    </div>

    <p><button @onclick="@ShowValues">Show values</button></p>

    @if (Display)
    {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var value in values)
            {
                <li>@value</li>

            }
        </ul>
    }

    @code {

        public void SetValue(string value)
        {
           values.Add(value);
        }

    private List<RenderFragment> componentListTest { get; set; }
    private List<string> values = new List<string>();
    private int currentCount { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        currentCount = 0;
        componentListTest = new List<RenderFragment>();
    }

    private bool Display;

    private void ShowValues()
    {
        if (values.Any())
        {
            Display = true;
        }
    }
    protected void addCompoment()
    {
        if (componentListTest == null)
        {
            componentListTest = new List<RenderFragment>();
        }
        componentListTest.Add(CreateDynamicComponent(currentCount));
        currentCount++;
    }


    RenderFragment CreateDynamicComponent(int counter) => builder =>
    {
        try
        {

           builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(MyCustomControl));
            builder.AddAttribute(1, "id", "listed-" + counter);
            builder.AddAttribute(2, "SetValue", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<System.String>>(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.Create<System.String>(this, this.SetValue )));
            builder.CloseComponent();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        };
    }
```

Note:

1. Notice the `SetValue` attribute I've added to the `CreateDynamicComponent`'s builder. This provides a Component Parameter to `MyCustomControl` of type `EventCallback<string>` which is assigned to the `SetValue` parameter property:

```
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> SetValue { get; set; }
```

And it is used (trigger the method which is also called `SetValue` in the parent component. You can change the name if you like) to pass the changed value from the child component to the parent component.

2. Use code instead of functions.
3. Note that I've made some modifications in your code: `OnInitialized` instead of `OnInit` (obsolete), sequence numbers should not created the way you do. Refer to [this article written by Steve Sanderson](https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/ec232992c2446ab9a0059dd0fbc5d0c3) ...

Hope this helps...

Comment: Purpose of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<System.String>>(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.Create<System.String> ? Here am using single textbox so we used string,If we have model class What we want to do?

Comment: TypeCheck actually ensure that the EventCallback factory may create the appropriate delegate with type specifier, a reference to the owner of the event, and the method to handle the event. This is something which I copied from code produced by the compiler, you don't really need to know it in order to program in Blazor, and of course it can be simplified.

Comment: As I've already mentioned in my answer, the solution to your issue can be devised in a couple of ways. However, I cannot answer your question specifically, as your question (in the common above) is not specific. In any case, you can create a service which store a Model or a list of Models, and inject this service into the parent and child components, so that whenever a child component create a new model (instead of just a string), the parent component would be able to access  the newly added Model instance.

Comment: Another viable solution is this: Define a Model or list of Model objects in your parent component (instead of a list of string as done in the current solution), capture a reference to the parent component, and pass it to the child component. You may pass "this" to the child components, so that they have direct access to the list of Model objects...

Comment: In my case i need to add one text box and one select box  when i click Add Button,and need to fetch the values when click on submit.